# Error adding existing repository onto PlasticSCM server

Tags: plasticscm

I'm trying to add some existing repositories into my PlasticSCM server so I can migrate the back end.

I'm using the following to attempt to do it:

```
cm addrep rep_11.plastic r11 localhost:8087
```

However this gives me the following error message:

```
The id specified in the repository database rep_11.plastic is not correct. 
It should be a number.
```

I can't seem to find this error message listed anywhere online, and I can't find any obvious non-numeric ID field in the database itself.

I've tried it with a number of them and they all give the same message. I'm not actually 100% sure which is which, so I'm using a generic repository name (`r11`) until I can have a look around them, but I'd assume that would be OK.

This is with default settings, so the SQLLite backend. I really need to get all these imported into it so they can be migrated to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

According to the command help:

Usage:

```
cm addrepository | addrep db_file rep_name repsvr_spec

db_file             The name of the database file on the database backend.
rep_name            The name of the repository.
repsvr_spec         Repository server specification:
                    [repserver:]svr_name:svr_port
```

In your example, please run:

```
cm addrep rep_11 r11 localhost:8087
```